# Output of order numbers and Revenue where all PO numbers tied to the order number has Shipped or is ready to Ship

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and trying to get an output of order numbers and Revenue where all PO numbers tied to the order number has Shipped or is ready to Ship. My table is called Orders and looks like this:

PO_NUM |    ORDER_NUM | STATUS | REVENUE 
101    | 001 | In Production | 1.00 
102 | 001 | Shipped |  1.00
103 | 001 | Shipped |      1.00
104 | 001 | Ready to Ship   | 1.00
201 | 002 | In Production   | 1.00
202 | 002 | In Production   | 1.00
203 | 002 | In Production   | 1.00
301 | 003 | Ready to Ship   | 1.00
401 | 004 | Shipped        | 1.00
402 | 004 | Shipped        | 1.00
403 | 004 | Shipped       |  1.00
501 | 005 | Ready to Ship | 1.00
502 | 005 | Shipped       |  1.00
503 | 005 | Shipped       |  1.00

Based on this table output would look like this:

ORDER_NUM | REVENUE
003     |   1.00
004     |   3.00
005     |   3.00

I am sure this is probably simple but I just can’t figure it out. Please help.

EDIT: I only want to return order numbers if status of all PO numbers tied to the Order number has shipped or is ready to be shipped.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, but here is one:

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, REVENUE 
FROM Orders 
WHERE PO_NUM IN(
  SELECT TOTALORDERS.PO_NUM 
  FROM
    (SELECT PO_NUM, count(*) as TOTAL 
    FROM Orders 
    GROUP BY PO_NUM) as TOTALORDERS
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT PO_NUM, count(*) as PROCESSED 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE [STATUS] IN('Shipped','Ready to Ship') 
    GROUP BY PO_NUM) as PROCESSEDORDERS
  ON TOTALORDERS.PO_NUM=PROCESSEDORDERS.PO_NUM 
    AND TOTALORDERS.TOTAL=PROCESSEDORDERS.PROCESSED)
```

Comment: This would not work. I only want to return order numbers if status of all PO numbers tied to the Order number has shipped or is ready to be shipped. Sorry for not being very clear.

Comment: Just got a chance to run this. For some reason it is still returning order numbers with that have P.O. numbers that are still in production.

Comment: Can you try running the sql inside the parentheses? It is just getting the total orders per PO and then the number processed per PO and then joining to make sure the total ordered per PO is equal to the number processed.